# Document in nested collection is immediately removed after reappearing adding it to the collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore and react to build my app.

This is how I add a document to the nested collection:

```js
const handleWatch = () => {
        if(watchedList.indexOf(foundProfile.id) > -1) {
            alert('User already in list');
        } else {
            db.collection("profiles")
                .doc(myProfile.id)
                .collection("watched")
                .add({
                    watchedUserId: foundProfile.id
                })
                .then(success => props.onWatchProfile())
        }
    }
```

And this is how I remove it:

```js
const handleUnwatch = (id) => {
        db.collection("profiles")
            .doc(myProfile.id)
            .collection("watched")
            .where("watchedUserId", "==", id)
            .onSnapshot(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(it => it.ref.delete()));
    }
```

and I'm testing the following path:

1. Add a user with nick X
2. Delete user with nick X
3. Add a user with nick X
4. Delete user with nick X

Points 1 and 2 work perfectly.
During point 3 the user is added to the nested collection but immediately is deleted. In the firestore console, I see a blinking document.

What is the reason? Maybe it is problem because of firestore's cache?

Comment: Are you deleting the document right after you read it?

Comment: Are you asking about deleting the document first time? Yes, the entire action takes about 5-10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test your code but I think this is because you don't [detach the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0#detach_a_listener) set in `handleUnwatch`. Therefore the listener is immediately triggered when you create a new doc and consequently deletes this doc (`.onSnapshot(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(it => it.ref.delete()));`).

The listener can be cancelled by calling the function that is returned when `onSnapshot` is called ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#onsnapshot)). Depending on your exact workflow you need to call this function when necessary.

For example:

```
const handleUnwatch = (id) => {
        const unsubscribe =  db.collection("profiles")
            .doc(myProfile.id)
            .collection("watched")
            .where("watchedUserId", "==", id)
            .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(it => it.ref.delete());
                unsubscribe();
            );
}
```

Again, the exact place where you call `unsubscribe()` depends on your exact functional requirements.

Comment: You are awesome man, it works! Thank you <3